# When refreshing a div Morris charts are disappear

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, morris.js

I want my charts and page data has to be changed at certain time without refreshing the page.

I used an [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) request to reload the page or specific div, but when I do that [morris.js](/questions/tagged/morris.js) charts are disappearing. Here is my [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) request. (actually I want full page refresh but if I do that it'll blink page and can't navigate through the page even if I change interval time to be longer).

```
function updateShouts() {
  var selectedAds = 1;
  var div = $('#refresh').html();
  $.ajax({
    url: "<?= base_url() ?>owner/dashBoard",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      selectedAds: selectedAds
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (status) {
        /* $("#refresh").load(location.href + " #refresh");*/
        location.reload();

      }

    }
  });
}
setInterval("updateShouts()", 4000);
updateShouts();
```

Comment: Are you refreshing the div(s) where the Morris charts are?

Comment: yes i'm refreshing div's.